# XPCOM FileOutptStream append does not work

Tags: file, append, xpcom, xulrunner

Has anyone managed to persuade XPCOM to do an append write to a local file? The code block below works fine with 0x08 (create if not exists) in the flags. But 0x10, append to the end of existing file just, plane don't work! Also the privilege bits 0666 dosen't. The file is always created 0644.

```js
Components.utils.import("resource://gre/modules/FileUtils.jsm");

var Cc=Components.classes;
var Ci=Components.interfaces;

function writeFile(fileName,data){
  var file = FileUtils.getFile("Home", [fileName]);

  var fileStream=FileUtils.openSafeFileOutputStream(file, 0x02 | 0x10 | 0x20, 0666, 0);
                                                             //  ^^^^ does not work! 0x08 does.

  fileStream.write(data,data.length);
  FileUtils.closeSafeFileOutputStream(fileStream);
}
```

I've tried opening the stream without using FileUtils. Like this:

```js
var fileStream = Cc["@mozilla.org/network/safe-file-output-stream;1"].
                   createInstance(Ci.nsIFileOutputStream);
fileStream.init(file, 0x02 | 0x10 | 0x20, 0666, 0);
```

With exactly similar results.

I running the code under XULRunner 1.9.2 as distributed with XUL Explorer 1.0a1pre, `Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US; rv:1.9.2.17) Gecko/20110421`.

Any clues would be much appreciated.

Comment: I think the problem is more un-subtle. I've looked into file.js File.prototype.open which is the destination of the mode flags. There I see at least 3 bugs in parameter passing! Open seems to be expecting a string, but the switch statement cases are numeric, consequently the only case is default. I'm digging deeper.

Answer (score 0):

The **safe** file output stream cannot append to files by definition. It is safe because it guarantees that either your changes will be written in full or you will get an exception and otherwise nothing will change. And that is implemented by writing to a **new** file and only renaming that file to replace the original one when the write operation is complete. Of course the side-effect of this approach is that you cannot append to a file because the write operation happens to a different file.

In Firefox/Gecko 7 or higher you can use [`FileUtils.openFileOutputStream()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript_code_modules/FileUtils.jsm#openFileOutputStream%28%29) to open a regular file output stream. In older versions you will need to use the "conventional" approach:

```js
var fileStream = Cc["@mozilla.org/network/file-output-stream;1"].
                   createInstance(Ci.nsIFileOutputStream);
fileStream.init(file, 0x02 | 0x10 | 0x20, 0666, 0);
```

Comment: I don't understand your definition of 'safe! I can write to the same file multiple times. Just can't append the way documentation suggests.

Comment: Looking at file-utils.js it would appear that 'safe' refers to permissions 644 is forced preventing executable and mode is forced to write, create and truncate.

Comment: It isn't my definition of "safe", it's what it means here. And of course you can write to the same file multiple times but each time your write goes to a temporary file and the target of the write operation is only replaced as the last step.

Answer (score 0):

How about this way:

```
function readFile(savefile) {
//alert('hi');
   try {
        netscape.security.PrivilegeManager.enablePrivilege("UniversalXPConnect");
    } catch (e) {
        alert("Permission to read file was denied.");
    }
    var file = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/file/local;1"]
        .createInstance(Components.interfaces.nsILocalFile);
    file.initWithPath( savefile );
    if ( file.exists() == false ) {
        alert("File does not exist");
    }
var data = "";
var fstream = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/network/file-input-stream;1"].
              createInstance(Components.interfaces.nsIFileInputStream);
var cstream = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/intl/converter-input-stream;1"].
              createInstance(Components.interfaces.nsIConverterInputStream);
fstream.init(file, -1, 0, 0);
cstream.init(fstream, "UTF-8", 0, 0); // you can use another encoding here if you wish

let (str = {}) {
  let read = 0;
  do {
    read = cstream.readString(0xffffffff, str); // read as much as we can and put it in str.value
    data += str.value;
  } while (read != 0);
}
```

You can read write 16/32/64 bit format by this method.

```
function saveFile(output, savefile)
{                                                            
    try {
        netscape.security.PrivilegeManager.enablePrivilege("UniversalXPConnect");
    } catch (e) {
        alert("Permission to save file was denied.");
    }
var file = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/file/local;1"].
createInstance(Components.interfaces.nsILocalFile);
    file.initWithPath( savefile );
    if ( file.exists() == false ) {
        alert( "File Updated Successfully ");
        file.create( Components.interfaces.nsIFile.NORMAL_FILE_TYPE, 420 );
    }
    var outputStream = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/network/file-output-stream;1"]
        .createInstance( Components.interfaces.nsIFileOutputStream );
    outputStream.init( file, 0x04 | 0x08 | 0x20, 420, 0 );
var converter = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/intl/converter-output-stream;1"].
                    createInstance(Components.interfaces.nsIConverterOutputStream);
    converter.init(outputStream, "UTF-8", 0, 0);
    converter.writeString(output);
    converter.close(); // this closes foStream

    outputStream.close();
//alert( "File Updated Successfully ");
}
```

You don't have import: `resource://gre/modules/FileUtils.jsm`

Answer (score -1):

SOLVED: Wladimir Palant is nearly right safe-file-output-stream can't append. However I also need to drop 0x20 (truncate) from the mode bits.

The following works:

```
Components.utils.import("resource://gre/modules/FileUtils.jsm");
var Cc=Components.classes;
var Ci=Components.interfaces;

function appendFile(fileName,data){
  var file = FileUtils.getFile("Home", [fileName]);
  var fileStream = Cc["@mozilla.org/network/file-output-stream;1"].
                     createInstance(Ci.nsIFileOutputStream);
  fileStream.init(file, 0x02 | 0x10 , 0666, 0);
  fileStream.write(data,data.length);
  fileStream.close();
}
```